# Deploying Django with Celeris to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have developed a django app using celery with redis in Heroku and it works fine in my virtual env.

I am trying to deploy the whole app to production in Heroku and can't find any docs or similar projects to use as guide.

There are a few tutorials about deploying django to heroku but nothing with celeris.

Could anyone tell me a step by step guide? or any tutorial or whatever?

Anything would help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at:

https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

You can learn from their configuration for Celery.